# Qual a diferença entre "baralhar" e "embaralhar"?

Tags: significado, verbos, diferenças, sinônimos

Sempre usei a palavra embaralhar, no entanto hoje no SOpt notei uma questão aonde estava escrita a palavra "baralhar", achei estranho e pesquisei, ambas são adjetivos e me parece que ambas podem ser usadas nas mesmas situações.

Tendo isto em vista;

- O que o **em**(baralhar) diferencia nas duas palavras?
- Existe momento certo para usar uma ou outra?
- Ambas são sinônimos ou é algo regional (por exemplo Portugal e Brasil)?

Comment: Por que a tag "adjetivo" se você está a falar de verbos?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Eu editei tão rápido logo que criei a pergunta que esqueci de alterar, no inicio falava de adjetivos mesmo :p - pode editar quando notar uma gafe

Answer (score 6):

Pelo que vi no dicionário de português são sinônimos:

## [Embaralhar](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/embaralhar)

> verbo transitivo
>
> O mesmo que baralhar.

## [Baralhar](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/baralhar)

> verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Misturar as cartas do baralho.
> 2. Meter a desordem em. verbo intransitivo
> 3. Andar às bulhas ou em contestações. verbo pronominal
> 4. Misturar-se.
> 5. Amotinar-se.

Answer (score 4):

No Brasil se usa *embaralhar*. Já *baralhar* é extremamente frequente na imprensa portuguesa, consequentemente deve ser também na fala local.

Comment: Em PT_BR nunca ouvi _baralhar_. Parece que falta um pedaço da palavra!